# Overloading with rvalue references

Tags: c++11, rvalue-reference

Perfect forwarding is great and all. But what do I do if I want to *not* perfectly forward and instead just overload, on something that happens to be a templated type?

```
template<typename T> void foo(T&& ref);
template<typename T> void foo(const T& ref);
```

Won't work because the first overload will invoke perfect forwarding. I'd really like behaviour very similar to if the first was a normal lvalue reference- where T will always be a value type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if
<
    !std::is_reference<T>::value,
    void
>::type
foo(T&& ref) {}

template<typename T> void foo(const T& ref) {}
```

Comment: I never think of the SFINAE solution, because MSVC's support sucks. Thanks :)

Comment: I don't know if support is better if you move the enable_if from the return type to the argument list?